# How to add external css/js in django2.2

Tags: django

How do i add an external css/js to my html template when working with django

i've tried some previously asked questions reply but seem like they're outdated and below is one of the procedure i followed

```
# after making sure the installed app has contrib.static then i make a file called static/my_apps/my.css
{%loadstatic%}
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{%static 'my_apps/my.css' %}"> 
     # i also tried {%loadstaticfile%} but none work
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating your project you have a specific django folder hierarchy and where you create your templates folder, at the same place create the folder with the name **static** and add all your static files (js/css/images) in it. and then while accessing use the **static** tag to access it in templates. **{%static 'path/to/your/static/files'%}** this path django engine takes from the static folder.